# How to plug Angularjs / Restangular Project with Django / Tastypie?

Tags: django, api, angularjs, tastypie, restangular

I'm trying to shape a project with AngularJs and Restangular, as a web app, and Django / Tastypie as an API called by the app.

I have :
 - an angular app doing well when run with the web-server script from the seed app.
 - a django / Tastypie API returning json when urls are called.

But I don't know how to connect them ! How do I start the app with my Django API ? How should I load it ? I don't find many examples on the web ...

Many many thanks for your help.

Comment: Although your question is not by the Stack Overflow guidelines and probably will be closed, trying to pinpoint you to the right direction, take a look at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bs5Qu8D6mYXzJXR74b87?p=info). The rest is easy if you just read the `Restangular` and `Tastypie` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There're two main integration libraries, [Djangular](https://github.com/appliedsec/djangular) and [Django-Angular](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Djangular provides various scenarios, but the one that makes most sense to me is this:

1. Create your Django app, and use Tastypie/DRF as you can to produce
   an API.
2. Use Djangular to create a new app with `manage.py startangularapp
   <app_name>`, which gives you the base layout for including angular.
3. Define a 'passthrough' url for each app, in your urls.py that points
   to an index.html for each app, which as minimum contains `<div
   ng-view></div>`.
4. In your `app.js` provide routes using the `$routeProvider`. You'll
   need to inject `DjangoProperties` in to the dependencies, and use
   `DjangoProperties.STATIC_URL` to get the right path.
5. Write a service that consumes the your API from `1.`
6. Write the rest of your AngularJS app around this API
7. Share and Enjoy!